# How to set up minimalistic indentation and code style in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Am finding it hard to work with Kotlin style of indentation, or at least the settings in my editor if that is not Kotlin's default. Code gets spread far too wide and it is hard to read. The image below best illustrates it. This happens anytime I paste new Kotlin code or use Android Studio's Auto Indent shortcut (CTRL + ALT + L). Is there any way to resolve this?

[image: Sample]

Comment: File | Settings | Code Style | Kotlin, change as you want it and save as default maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured that you have to uncheck `Line Breaks` option if checked found in:
File | Settings | Code Style | Kotlin| Wrapping And Braces | Keep when reformatting | Line Breaks